# Is it normal for the system to take a long time in "bundle install" every time I create a new rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundle-install

I am new to Ruby and trying to set it up to learn ruby and rails development.

Everytime I create a new rails app, the system takes about 5-10 minutes to "bundle install"

Considering that these are the same bundles that I have installed multiple times before, should the system recognize that they are already installed and pick them up from their location?

Or is it normal for it to do a fresh install everytime?

Comment: i think this is probably more dependent on your internet connection - the bundles aren't cached locally

Answer (score 0):

I use a standard issue Macbook Pro 13" and it takes me about 4-5 minutes to "bundle install" a new rails app at home and less than 2 minutes at work, so it mostly is dependent on your internet connection is my theory. I have 30mb down at home and obviously a 1Tb at work.

10 minutes seems a bit excessive though, unless you have really slow internet. Maybe look at opening some ports on your router for ruby?